# Web page(html) scraping using C#

Tags: c#, html, regex, xpath

This is just a general question. Currently I am doing webpage scraping using regex. But I think it is sometimes too difficult to figure out the regular expression, so I am thinking is XSL/XPath an alternative to regex in C#?

Also, I would like to know if there are more advanced techniques for webpage scraping other than the two listed above. Thanks.

Comment: xsl/xpath requires that the page is XHTML 1.0, not all html conforms to something that is easily consumed by an xml parser

Comment: @rene: is this a clean-cut? If the webpage is XHTML1.0, the Xpath can be used in C#, if it is not XHTML1.0, then just seek other alternatives?

Comment: There is a difference between the claim (in the doctype) about xhtml 1.0 and actually being xhtml 1.0 compliant. No, sorry, no clean-cuts. But it looks you already have a great answer

Comment: surprisingly enough, the best answers to a question like this have been posted in an older and more specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065526/pulling-data-from-a-webpage-parsing-it-for-specific-pieces-and-displaying-it/33756899

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may take a look at [SgmlReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/SgmlReader) or [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) which are HTML parsing libraries for .NET.

Comment: From the NuGet package manager, run: `Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack`  and you're set :)

Comment: @Martinho, personally I prefer `SgmlReader` but `Html Agility Pack` works also fine :-)

Comment: does this imply using <SgmlReader> to transform html to a well-formed xml, then do Xpath to that xml document in C#?

Comment: @Robert, yes you get an XmlDocument from your HTML page which gives you full access to the DOM tree.

Comment: For completeness: you can also do queries with jQuery-like CSS selectors using [Fizzler](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler). Currently it works with the HtmlAgilityPack, but I believe there are plans to support other parsing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to gather data from a web page is [WebsiteParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebsiteParser). It's based on Html Agility Pack and you can simply describe your properties using attributes and CSS selectors.

Github [here](https://github.com/jasniec/WebsiteParser)