# Chrome copy XPath returning null when using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm following the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18066671

```
string Url = "http://www.owgr.com/ranking";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
        string worldRanking = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"ranking_table\"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")[0].InnerText;
```

But the Xpath is returning a null reference.
I've tried several variations but nothing's working, I've never used XPath before, am I missing something?

Comment: are you sure, your doc contains table and div??

Comment: here is the result that i got by running `ranking_table` only. "RAnkings per page \n All \n 25 \n 50 \n 100 \n 150"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my XPath query (scraping HTML tables) only work in Firebug, but not the application I'm developing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `<tbody/>` element in that table, remove the `/tbody` axis step and your query works totally fine. See "[Why does my XPath query (scraping HTML tables) only work in Firebug, but not the application I'm developing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the)" for details.

Additional hint: XPath also supports single quotes for strings, so you don't need to escape the double quotes.

This XPath expression will return the element you're looking for:

```
//*[@id='ranking_table']/div[2]/table/tr[1]/td[1]
```