# Getting a number from a webpage and storing it as an int

Tags: c#, html

I want to retrieve my Bitcoin mining hashrate from my pool webpage and store it as an int so that I can print it to the console. I tried using the *HtmlAgilityPack* which never seemed to have worked while using this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Url = "http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/halo-spartan-assault";
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

    string metascore = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"main\"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/a/span[1]")[0].InnerText;
    string userscore = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"main\"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/span[1]")[0].InnerText;
    string summary = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"main\"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li/span[2]/span/span[1]")[0].InnerText;
}
```

From [this Stack Exchange question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065526/pulling-data-from-a-webpage-parsing-it-for-specific-pieces-and-displaying-it) This ended up being confusing and I couldn't figure out how to make it return the desired value.

Is there any simpler or more intuitive way of getting this value?

Comment: AngleSharp is HTML parsing library that uses CSS selectors, maybe it will help with XPath hell here

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I'll try it out.