# Find value using ID from webBrowser and put it in text box in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the value of an ID from a website and put that into a textbox.

The website code looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="recaptcha-token" value="03AHJ_VuuR2VbfWFbLvWo0XyfL7hkbAy1-t5M21_0SV41kwmq0uJSfQ-JuhImRLjcAJVAUMdNCoVI3mpsfZz2_NpW2LsIyeGMEzkHf1qjCQ_WTWWr4ujJFsbn6TOzY1V01UNliQQVYR-q6Z3sPIN-zlbTp_gMIIHj_2ZGgKWedEki6Cwwt397IELj2mBlntwmd2uV8aTCYnkTiwmhIz7jcChOuBhxZNMToVVuo9-5VnaRmRypmBmXPagU8qa9pCcU_Jml5V0dVuZHNsssrsCG_hsw7foo_UbXvCPXaaZfDoMtJe4XTCMc8toEUtqJJGj1kTU4HhZy6cXCJpcVqTaqqwH8PsZapgDlSxP-CcjbdGxcgaqwyRkhrrcOfrF_qCeGfdw_3osXg652j62lh86ZhPfMldYEwrmvzPWLKwMOCdouTGV3WkNJhWRA">
```

I'm trying to get the part after value=.
I'm not very good at coding but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065526/pulling-data-from-a-webpage-parsing-it-for-specific-pieces-and-displaying-it

Comment: I tried `textBox19.Text = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("recaptcha-token").GetAttribute("value");`