# XML and JSP parsing in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML feed file and I don`t know how to handle a problem.
So, the code is:

```
<PRICE>
<WIC>GA-H110M-S2H</WIC>
<DESCRIPTION>
GIGABYTE Main Board Desktop INTEL H110 (Socket LGA1151,2xDDR4,VGA/HDMI/DVI,1xPCIEX16/2xPCIEX1,USB3.0/USB2.0, 6xSATA III,LAN) micro ATX retail
</DESCRIPTION>
<VENDOR_NAME>GIGABYTE</VENDOR_NAME>
<GROUP_NAME>Main Board Desktop</GROUP_NAME>
<VPF_NAME/>
<CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
<AVAIL>0</AVAIL>
<RETAIL_PRICE>56.40</RETAIL_PRICE>
<MY_PRICE>52.71</MY_PRICE>
<WARRANTYTERM>36</WARRANTYTERM>
<GROUP_ID>32</GROUP_ID>
<VENDOR_ID>170192</VENDOR_ID>
<SMALL_IMAGE>
https://www.it4profit.com/catalogimg/wic/1/GA-H110M-S2H
</SMALL_IMAGE>
<PRODUCT_CARD>
https://content.it4profit.com/itshop/itemcard_cs.jsp?ITEM=151118121920215716&THEME=asbis&LANG=ro
</PRODUCT_CARD>
<EAN>4719331837310</EAN>
</PRICE>
```

Now, in PRODUCT_CARD are technical information for that product and I don`t know how to extract all data and then export to .csv using C# for example.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried , but I am suggesting can do , this 
Credits: [Pulling data from a webpage, parsing it for specific pieces, and displaying it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065526/pulling-data-from-a-webpage-parsing-it-for-specific-pieces-and-displaying-it)

```
    string Url = "https://content.it4profit.com/itshop/itemcard_cs.jsp?ITEM=151118121920215716&THEME=asbis&LANG=ro";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
```

Comment: Did you just copy the xpath from the answer in that link?

Comment: @hans , yes , although I have edited it, did for reference.

Comment: I think you should edit your answer. This code only loads the page, not parsing it. And the previous code might use the wrong xpath. I think it's better to post code that works or just post the link so TC or readers can do something by themselves based on the answer in that link.

Answer (score 0):

Real simple to get into dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("PRICE").Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "press any key to continue..." this is the result